# Non-interactive creation of SSL certificate requests

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, command-line-interface, openssl

Is there a way to create SSL cert requests by specifying all the required parameters on the initial command? I am writing a [CLI-based web server control panel](https://github.com/dotancohen/burton) and I would like to avoid the use of [expect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) when executing `openssl` if possible.

**This is a typical way to create a cert request:**

```
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -keyout foobar.com.key -out foobar.com.csr
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.................................................+++
........................................+++
writing new private key to 'foobar.com.key'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:New Sweden
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Stockholm
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Scandanavian Ventures, Inc.
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:foobar.com
Email Address []:gustav@foobar.com

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:FooBar
```

**I am hoping to see something like this:** *(unworking example)*

```
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 -keyout foobar.com.key -out foobar.com.csr \
-Country US \
-State "New Sweden" \
-Locality Stockholm \
-Organization "Scandanavian Ventures, Inc." \
-CommonName  foobar.com \
-EmailAddress gustav@foobar.com \
-Company FooBar
```

The fine man page had nothing to say on the matter, nor was I able to find anything via Google. **Must SSL cert request generation be an interactive process, or is there some way to specify all the parameters in a single command?**

This is on a Debian-derived Linux distro running `openssl 1.0.1`.

Comment: http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1073-bash-script-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-key-and-request-csr

Comment: @ceejayoz: Very nice, thank you. א) Where are those `openssl` flags documented? ב) What did you google for to find that? Thank you!

Comment: I googled "CSR generate script". The `-subj` parameter is documented (not in much detail) at https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html.

Comment: It is also possible to create a config file, typically called `openssl.cnf`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you are missing two part:

the subject line, which can be called as

```
-subj "/C=US/ST=New Sweden/L=Stockholm /O=.../OU=.../CN=.../emailAddress=..."
```

- replacing ... with value, `X=` being X509 code (**O**rganisation/**O**rganisation**U**nit/etc ... )

the password value, which can be called as

```
-passout pass:client11
-passin  pass:client11
```

- which give an output/input password

my calling for new key looks like

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out lib/client1.key -passout pass:client11 1024
openssl rsa -in lib/client1.key -passin pass:client11 -out lib/client1-nokey.key

openssl req -new -key lib/client1.key \
    -passin pass:client11 -out lib/client1.csr \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=New Sweden/L=Stockholm/O=.../OU=.../CN=.../emailAddress=..."
```

Answer (score 7):

I append to my regular openssl command:

> openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 7300 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/key.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/cert.pem

This line:

```
-subj "/C=PE/ST=Lima/L=Lima/O=Acme Inc. /OU=IT Department/CN=acme.com"
```

Description:

- Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:PE
- State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Lima
- Locality Name (eg, city) []:Lima
- Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Acme Inc.
- Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:IT Department
- Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:acme.com

Use "/" like separator.

Comment: It seems that the accepted answer already includes this information. Otherwise, thank you.

Comment: Upvoted since this answer better explains the data to put into the `-subj` line

Answer (score 2):

Check for `-batch` option as described in the [official docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-req.html).

Comment: Thank you. I see that the batch option exists, but there seems to be no explanation of how to use it.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? Is batch not a possible solution to the issue? From the name, it sounds like it just might be.

Comment: It's definitely only way to do this with -batch option, why downvoted I have no idea. Statement "The fine man page had nothing to say on the matter" is false, because of "-batch" option.

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning batch, as even though I didn't use it in the solution it may come in handy in the future.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be very useful, as it doesn't explain _how_ to use that option (neither does the doc). Using `-batch` without `-subj` causes the command to fail, while using `-subj` without `-batch` works just fine, so it's unclear what benefit `-batch` provides, if any.

Comment: `-subj` is not sufficient for generating wildcard, SAN, or other certificate types that require additional configuration. So you would use `-batch` along with `-config` in order to skip the interactive prompts, providing that you've supplied the necessary subject information either in the config.